# MySQL/MariaDB Remote Access over NodeJS in Docker Stack

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, mariadb

I've built a Docker stack running several services:
Important:
- DB (MariaDB)
- API (NodeJS)

The DB User is initialized as following:

```
CREATE USER 'remote'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '#####';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON mydatabase.* TO 'remote'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I'm establashing the MySQL Connection in my Typescript like this:

```
import ENV from "dotenv";
...
private connection = MySql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASESERVER,
    user: SecretStorage.getSecret('api_sql_user'),
    password: SecretStorage.getSecret('api_sql_pass'),
    database: process.env.DATABASE,
    multipleStatements: true //TODO: Muss ausgeschalten werden
});
```

using

```
const fs = require('fs');
export class SecretStorage{
    public static getSecret(secretID:string):string{
        return fs.readFileSync("/run/secrets/" + secretID);
    }
}
```

and

```
export DATABASE=mydatabase
export DATABASESERVER=db
```

When I try to do some operations via the NodeJS, I'm getting

```
Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'remote'@'10.0.35.4' (using password: YES)
```

However, when I exec into the docker container, installing a mysql client and do

```
mysql -p####### -uremote -hdb mydatabase
```

I can successful conntect to mydatabase (and do operations).

Does anyone have ideas?
Thanks! :) And stay healthy!

Answer (score 0):

The Issue the following:
When I read from a file, the string will also contain a line break at the end.

So I had to change the getSecret Function like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
export class SecretStorage{
    public static getSecret(secretID:string,OneLine:boolean=false):string{
        if(OneLine){
            return fs.readFileSync("/run/secrets/" + secretID).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"")
        } else{
            return fs.readFileSync("/run/secrets/" + secretID);
        }
    }
}
```